# How can I do a check if current user is following current site?

Tags: 2013, user-controls, user-accounts, following

I have a usercontrol and inside its ascx.cs file I would like to do a check(if) if current user is following the current site.

How can I accomplish that?

So far I have done something like this:

```
SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentSite);
            var currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
            var profile = new UserProfileManager(context);
            var user = profile.GetUserProfile(currentUser);
            SPSocialFollowingManager followingManager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(user, context);
```

`SPSocialFollowingManager` have a method called `IsFollowed()` which determines whether the current user is following the specified actor.

I guess that I need to use that one?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. See the following code:

```
SPSocialActorInfo actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(SPContext.Current.Url);

bool doesCurrentUserFollowCurrentSite = followingManager.IsFollowed(actorInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is that all that is required? Or do I need to have any of my code in your code snippit aswell?

Comment: Yup this snippet will run after your code